# iOS 5: troubles with UITabBarControllerDelegate

Tags: ios, ios5

Header file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface PFXTabControllerViewController : UITabBarController <UITabBarControllerDelegate>
@end
```

Implementation file:

```
#import "PFXTabControllerViewController.h"

@interface PFXTabControllerViewController ()
@end

@implementation PFXTabControllerViewController

- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item {
    NSLog(@"tabBar didSelectItem");
}

- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    NSLog(@"tabBarController didSelectViewController");
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.tabBarController.delegate = self; // Tried it both with and without this.
}
```

The `UITabBarcontroller` shows just fine, with the tab bar. Clicking on a tab fires `didSelectItem` but it does not fire `didSelectViewController` which is the event I need to handle. The `UITabBarcontroller` is loading and showing different subclasses of `UIViewController`.

**UPDATE** Changing that `self.tabBarController.delegate = self` line to `self.delegate = self` works, and both fire. I don't understand why this is necessary. Setting `self.delegate = self` seems... silly. Any ideas?

Comment: PFXTabControllerViewController extends UITabBarController. I am baffled that self.tabBarController actually does not throw an exception as a UITabBarController does not have a member called tabBarController.

Comment: Why would `self.delegate = self` wire up the delegate appropriately? Seems goofy.

Comment: That is entirely fine. UITabBarController is not really meant to be subclassed but to be extended via delegation. As you are doing both, you need to setup both. The delegate methods are not implemented within the original implementation, hence the delegate property usually is not set towards self.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the header as follows :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface PFXTabControllerViewController : **UIViewController** <UITabBarControllerDelegate>
@end
```